# Strange behavior with dimensions of canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html5-canvas

So, I'm confused about a current problem, which thankfully is easy to demonstrate to you guys.

Here it is on JSFiddle:

[Using the canvas](http://jsfiddle.net/7g44k16x/): `upper.height=$(document.body).height() - lower.height();`

[Using a substitute div](http://jsfiddle.net/h400jkt7/): `upper.height($(document.body).height() - lower.height());`

As you can see, a small margin of a few pixels is placed after the canvas for some reason.  It ends up creating a scrollbar, since it becomes 4 pixels taller than the viewport it's trying to fill.  Why is this?  I've set `margin:0;` and `padding:0;` for all elements.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `canvas` as a block element (a `div` is block level by default), it is inline by default which is why you are seeing the variation in behaviour:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/7g44k16x/1/)

```
canvas{
    display:block
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  I feel a bit dumb for not seeing that.